# Search for string based on condition and print till next matching string

Tags: bash

### I'm looking for a solution for this problem. I got a file with the output as shown below:

```
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x00E2
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 32 bits
    Data Width: 32 bits
    Size: 512 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: RAM slot #0
    Bank Locator: RAM slot #0
    Type: DRAM
    Type Detail: EDO
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x00E2
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: RAM slot #1
    Bank Locator: RAM slot #1
    Type: DRAM
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x00E2
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: RAM slot #2
    Bank Locator: RAM slot #2
    Type: DRAM
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x00E2
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: RAM slot #3
    Bank Locator: RAM slot #3
    Type: DRAM
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
```

---

Here, each paragraph begins with "Memory Device", so i want to search for each paragraph which got the "Size" Column with numerical value and print only those paragraphs. So, I don't need to print any paragraphs which got the value of size as "Size: No Module Installed". This is partial output of the command `"dmidecode --type memory"`.
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that the output is always formatted the same way you can just do

```
grep -E '[[:blank:]]Size: [0-9]+' mem.txt -A 11 -B 6
```

[edit] -B 10 worked just because only the first entry had a numeric size. -B 6 should work better. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: This assumes all records have a fixed number of lines before and after `Size:`.  It might work better with `-B6`. :)

Comment: Hence: "Provided that the output is always formatted the same way..."

Comment: You might still want to edit the `-B` thing though.

Comment: Didn't catch that edit. Tnx

Comment: Thanks evading, that worked like a charm! Kudos

Comment: evading, if i want to print this output in perfect columns  using awk with separator being ":", how can this done.